# Server Error 500 Django Digital Ocean

Tags: django, postgresql

i've deployed my django project in digital ocean, I'm getting Server Error(500), however the url is showing me `myipaddress/accounts/login/?next=/` . I could n't figure out what is causing error. I've kept `DEBUG=False` even in settings.py

Comment: Try to set `DEBUG = True` to see a more detailed error.

Comment: Thanks, tried it, there's a problem with static folder anf media folder, glad it worked now.